# In Pyglet is there way to bring sprites to foreground

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I am trying to bring sprites to the foreground so that they are on the top layer of an image. This is the line i am using to assign the value of the image

`ball = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ball_image, 50, 50)`

Is there a property that i can add to this line that will draw the image on the foreground ?

edit: I am trying to keep the first image stay in the foreground regardless if its drawn before or after the second image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What both you (OP) and two commenters fail to realize is that [GKBRK's answer](/a/45351754) is actually an applicable solution to your question. Because rendering the thing you want on top - last - will actually solve this problem.

OpenGL doesn't have "layers" predefined. This is up to the developer to solve.  OpenGL's sole purpose is to communicate with the graphics card in a predefined set of rules. You use these rules to create something you understand, pass it to OpenGL and it converts it to something the graphics card understands.

You simply have to create a placeholder (a variable) containing the foreground, and render that **last** in the chain of objects to be rendered.

Normally this placeholder is a [Pyglet Batch](//pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/programming_guide/graphics.html#batched-rendering).

How it works is:

```
import pyglet

key = pyglet.window.key

class main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__ (self, width=800, height=600, fps=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(main, self).__init__(width, height, *args, **kwargs)
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0

        ## == an example of batched rendering:
        self.main_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

        ## == Set up two ordered groups.
        ##    Again, you still have to place the foreground LAST in the queue.
        self.background = pyglet.graphics.OrderedGroup(0)
        self.foreground = pyglet.graphics.OrderedGroup(1)

        self.bg = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('background.png'), batch=self.main_batch, group=self.background)

        self.sprites = {}
        self.sprites['player'] = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('player.png'), batch=self.main_batch, group=self.foreground, x = 10, y = 50)
        self.sprites['enemy'] = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('foe.png'), batch=self.main_batch, group=self.foreground, x = 50, y = 200)

        self.x = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('foreground.png'), batch=self.main_batch, group=self.foreground, x=200, y=400)

        self.alive = 1

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE: # [ESC]
            self.alive = 0

    def render(self):
        ## == Clear the frame
        self.clear()

        self.main_batch.draw()

        ## == And flip the current buffer to become the active viewed buffer.
        self.flip()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()

            # -----------> This is key <----------
            # This is what replaces pyglet.app.run()
            # but is required for the GUI to not freeze
            #
            event = self.dispatch_events()

x = main()
x.run()
```

But you could also just do:

```
def render():
    self.clear()
    self.bg.draw()
    for s_name, sprite_object in self.sprites.items():
        sprite_object.draw()
    self.foreground.draw()
    self.flip()
```

It's essentially the same thing.. but a LOT slower.

But I stand by GKBRK's answer; it is correct.. And with the absolute lack of code from the OP - it's hard to give any code as a example unless you happen to sit on some (as I do).

My code is not necessarily applicable to the OP's code - so this will most likely just be confusing or not a good match of code style. But this is how it works at least.

Comment: I think the keyword here is OrderedGroup which is the prefered pyglet way to achieve what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing the sprite you want to be on the top later than the bottom sprites should accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to keep the first image in the foreground regardless if a second image is drawn in the same area.I want to do this because the images are not going to be drawn in the same sequence each time.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: @TobySpeight and John Moutafis. You are both correct, normally an answer should demonstrate the solution. However, since the OP failed to give at least a minimal working example of what he's trying to accomplish with especial regard to the claim that this solution isn't applicable because the sprites are rendered in random order - I fail to see how this doesn't solve the question. The question is vague, and based on this any answer will be vague and not fully easily demonstrated on the OP's implementation. The question should be flagged if anything.

Comment: @Torxed, I agree to some extent, though I would say that **a poor question doesn't deserve a poor answer** - it's more useful (to the world, if not to the OP) to either list assumptions that were necessary to provide a complete, demonstrable answer, or if that's not possible, to work to improve the question until it's precise enough to be answered clearly.  Thanks for taking the former approach where I don't have the knowledge to do so - I've upvoted your answer.